# ClassCastException from using toArray() method

Tags: java

I am writing junit test for toArray method which is one of the method of `ArrayBasedStack`. This class has an array inside and toArray method copies the element and return. The method is given by the class, and I amd trying to print out each element in the array.

This method copy the local array and return the copy array with the type of the Object.

```
public T[] toArray() {
    T[] copy = (T[]) new Object[this.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        copy[i] = (T) this.myArray[i];
    }

    return copy;
}
```

For the test, I set up String array as like below:

private ArrayBasedStack stack;

```
public void setUp(){
    stack = new ArrayBasedStack<String>();
}
```

To test toArray() method, I tried:

```
   public void testToArray(){
        stack.push("000");
        stack.push("111");
        assertEquals(2, stack.toArray().length);
        assertEquals("111", stack.toArray()[0]);
    }
```

Other than toArray() method, other methods' test passed well such as: `peek()`, `push()`, `clear()`, `equals()`... etc.

However, only this test returns error for both `assertEquals`:

```
    assertEquals(2, stack.toArray().length);
    assertEquals("111", stack.toArray()[0]);
```

The error is:

```
>java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
        at arraystack.ArrayBasedStackTest.testToArray(ArrayBasedStackTest.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well yes, you're creating an `Object[]`, and then when you call it, that's effectively casting to `String[]`, and that cast isn't valid. Basically, you can't create the right kind of array without actually knowing the element type at execution time.

Comment: Have you considered using `Arrays.copyOf()` to copy the internal array?  You should be able to get a *bona fide* `T[]` (i.e. `String[]`) that way.  And no casting needed.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Answer (score 2):

```
    T[] copy = (T[]) new Object[this.size()];
```

Here you are lying to the compiler. It isn't a `T[]`, unless `T[]` is `Object[]`.

The correct way to write this method is the same way `Collections` do it, by supplying a prototype that if you're lucky is already the right size:

```
import java.lang.ref.Array;

public T[] toArray(T[] a)
{
    if (a.length != this.size())
    {
        a = Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), this.size());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
    {
        a[i] = (T) this.myArray[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public T[] toArray(T[] a)
{
    return Arrays.copyOf(this.myArray, this size());
}
```